# Why does shifting a value further than its size not result in 0?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

**Actual refined question:**

Why does this not print 0?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned char barray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    unsigned long weirdValue = barray[3] << 32;

    std::cout << weirdValue; // prints 4
    std::string bla;
    std::getline(std::cin, bla);
    return 0;
}
```

The disassembly of the shift operation:

```
   10:  unsigned long weirdValue = barray[3] << 32;
00411424  movzx       eax,byte ptr [ebp-1Dh] 
00411428  shl         eax,20h 
0041142B  mov         dword ptr [ebp-2Ch],eax
```

---

**Original question:**

I found the following snippet in some old code we maintain. It converts a byte array to multiple float values and adds the floats to a list. Why does it work for byte arrays greater than 4?

```
unsigned long ulValue = 0;
for (USHORT usIndex = 0; usIndex < m_oData.usNumberOfBytes;  usIndex++)
{
    if (usIndex > 0 && (usIndex % 4) == 0)
    {
        float* pfValue = (float*)&ulValue;
        oValues.push_back(*pfValue);
        ulValue = 0;
    }

    ulValue += (m_oData.pabyDataBytes[usIndex] << (8*usIndex)); // Why does this work for usIndex > 3?? 
}
```

I would understand that this works if << was a rotate operator, not a shift operator. Or if it was

```
ulValue += (m_oData.pabyDataBytes[usIndex] << (8*(usIndex%4)))
```

But the code like i found it just confuses me.

The code is compiled using VS 2005.
If i try the original snippet in the immediate window, it doesn't work though.

I know how to do this properly, i just want to know why the code and especially the shift operation works as it is.

Edit: The disassembly for the shift operation is:

```
13D61D0A  shl         ecx,3   // multiply uIndex by 8
13D61D0D  shl         eax,cl  // shift to left, does nothing for multiples of 32
13D61D0F  add         eax,dword ptr [ulValue] 
13D61D15  mov         dword ptr [ulValue],eax
```

So the disassembly is fine.

Comment: What the code is doing is actually incorrect. You can't do [type-punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) except explicitly through an array of `char`. Using the intermediate `ulValue` turns the code into something illegal and is technically *undefined behavior*. And it will not work on all platforms due to endianness and possible differences in size between `long` and `float`.

Comment: How sure are you that it actually works ? Will usNumberOfBytes ever be > 3 when this is run in the real world ? Currently the code can not work for usIndex > 3

Comment: I wonder why it is working here. And i know there are better solutions, i just want to know why this worked for over a decade. And yes, i have a case where usNumberOfBytes is 28

Comment: A possible working and correct way might be to do e.g. `float fValue = *(float*) &m_oData.pabyDataBytes[usIndex]` and then increase `usIndex` with `sizeof(float)`.

Comment: I don't need a working and correct way, i want to know why this works.

Comment: So what you're really asking about is the shift operation and why it "works"? Perhaps you can clarify it a little, and remove the unrelated code? Preferably create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? And actually it *shouldn't* work. If `sizeof(unsigned long) == 4` then it will shift to many bits when `usIndex > 3` and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: As for discovering why it *seemingly* works, you need to examine the assembly code for the code you show. And possibly step through the assembly code in a debugger to see what it actually does.

Comment: The code has undefined behaviour. Anyone who sold you the code as working, or who took salary from you claiming they'd write working code, was conning you.

Comment: Why don't you Show the type of m_oData and of oValues? Why is oValues present? Is it necessary for an [mcve]?

Comment: I added a minimal, complete, and eventually verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shift count is masked to 5 bits, which limits the range to 0-31.

A shift of 32 therefore is same as a shift of zero.

http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html